# Splitting of complexes iff f is homotopic to zero in the category of complexes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

I am trying the understand the forward direction what is the homotopy here that forces f to be homotopic to zero ? [image]

Comment: What book are you reading from?

Answer (score 0):

Looking as this, $s$ would have to be a map of complexes from $X[1]$
to $Y$. This does appear to be the sort of thing that might be a chain
homotopy of chain maps from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Yeah but which s should it be ? We have to construct it somehow from $\sigma$, but I am not sure how.

Comment: The chain homotopy is the component of the splitting map that maps $X[1]$ to $Y$. Checking that this is a chain homotopy is definition-unraveling, which you ought to be able to do. (Ask yourself: what is the definition of a chain homotopy? How are these properties implied by the definition of a map of complexes $X[1]\to Y$?)